# find the count of checked checkboxes using protractor

Tags: protractor

I want to do protractor testing in my AngularJS application where my need is to find the count of checked checkboxes. There are about 44 checkboxes in a page out of which only 4 are checked.I wrote below code where the console prints 
true,false,false,true,false,false,true,false,false,true; etc.

How to find how many true values are there?

```
var rows = element.all(by.model("accordoptionGroup[optgroup.id][objopt.id].value"));    
rows.isSelected().then(function(isSelect){
console.log(isSelect);  
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a *better way* - use [`filter()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter):

```
var rows = element.all(by.model("accordoptionGroup[optgroup.id][objopt.id].value"));
var count = rows.filter(function (row) {
    return row.isSelected().then(function (isSelected) {
        return isSelected;
    });
}).count();
expect(count).toEqual(4);
```

Comment: @Jinu: This is a better approach, please use this !

Comment: Based on above, is it possible to get count number into a variable? I would  like to use it in a calculation.

Comment: @jurijk use this `count` variable, resolve the promise explicitly with `count.then(function (actualCount) { ... })` and use the `actualCount` resolved count integer value.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this -

```
 var rows = element.all(by.model("accordoptionGroup[optgroup.id][objopt.id].value"));    

 rows.isSelected().then(function(selected){
 count =0;
 for(i=0;i<rows.length<i++) {
 if(selected) {
  count++;
  }
 }
 expect(count).toEqual(4); // to check 4 checkboxes are checked
 });
```

Then you could try giving a for loop and iterating it if selected it returns true and you can get the count!

Comment: I tried this earlier.But giving error as below,                                                Failed: isSelect.count is not a function

Comment: I updated my code, please check and let me know if it works !